# Add triangle under current active page link/make current page highlighted while on it

Tags: html

i'm currently editing a new layout for my tumblr and i was wondering if there was a way to add a small triangle sort of like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sGnd.png

to a current link, by current a mean, every page that is clicked/a person is currently on it would have a triangle under its link.

i have a menu bar that'll have all the links (can be seen here: http://mains-tester.tumblr.com/) and i'm trying to do two things, make it so that current page is highlighted on the menu bar and it has a small triangle under it. I'm trying to figure out is theres a way to just add the triangle to every link without having to go and do each and every single one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite easy to add this sort of effect using the pseudo-class `:after`.

Ensuring that `position: relative` for the `<a>` tag, you can add this CSS which will add a white arrow at the bottom centred.

```
.linkage:hover:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  /* Ads an arrow effect exploiting the way that browsers join borders together */
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid #fff;
  /* centers relative to parent */
  left: 50%;
  /* Compensates for width of border (arrow) */
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

I've set up a demo of it working here (with most of the same css you have used): http://jsfiddle.net/QybKW/4/

If you would prefer not to rely on CSS trickery, you could create a PNG image file and set the background of the pseudo element giving it a positive width and height.

Comment: you are a god send! thank you so very much! but is there a way to make it remain with the arrow/box while on the current page?

Comment: Youre welcome! =) And I'm not sure which classes tumblr provides, but if you can get an `<a>` tag to have a specific class when the user is on that page, then you could add another CSS match, like this: `.linkage.open:after` and your resulting CSS code will look like this: `.linkage:hover:after, .linkage.open:after { ... }`

Comment: ...obviously the class `open` can be whatever class you would like, or one that tumble uses of you are limited! =)

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't seem to work! :( maybe i did it wrong or tumblr's just not allowing it.

Comment: Actually yes, it doesn't look like tumblr supports current page in themes: [http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#pages](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#pages) you will be able to add some javascript code though to check each a tag of the navigation to see if we are on that current page, and if so, add the open class to the tag! :-)